# How to measure starting and ending 'x' and 'y' co-ordinates of a View in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to move a circle from top to bottom inside of a View. For top I simply figured out y = 0.

How can I measure the y co-ordinate for the end of a view.

[image: image of my idea]

I tried Dimensions, but the height and width are different from coordinates.

My app uses **`Animated.ValueXY({ x: xCordinate, y: yCordinate })`**
The `xCordinate` and `yCordinate` get passed from a function that changes coordinates.

```
Animated.timing(this.moveAnimation, {
duration: 1000,
toValue: {x: xCordinate, y: yCordinate},
}).start();
```

I managed random value for my phone but it is not same for all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native provides a `onLayout` method that gets triggered every time your view renders. Here's a sample code.

```
onLayout = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
      x: e.nativeEvent.layout.x,
      y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y
    })
  }

  render (
    <View onLayout={this.onLayout}>
      <Text>Hamza Waleed</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```